# Deepanimebot on Docker: Mismatch between number of layers in weight file and model

Tags: python-2.7, docker, dockerfile, hdf5, keras

I load the [DeepClassificationBot](https://github.com/AntreasAntoniou/DeepClassificationBot) (`classificationbot/deploy-base:latest`) docker image and modify it with custom model (data, categories and model weights). Looks like only model and weights are needed.

The model works well locally, but when deploying it as webapp inside docker container, it gives:

> Exception: You are trying to load a weight file containing 45 layers
>   into a model with 34 layers.

It looks as if the model (Keras+HDF5) and the weight file are not matching each other.

Here seem to be their locations (the root folder contains just some `.py` scripts). I am already copying those folders that contain the HDF5 model and weights:

```
data # This is where the extracted and preprocessed data are saved.
-categories.p
-data.hdf5
-README.md
pre_trained_weights # This is where the trained model weights are saved.
-latest_model_weights.hdf5
-model_weights.hdf5
-README.md
```

The problem might be in the Dockerfile (some required file not being copied):

`~/DeepClassificationBot-master/dockerfiles/webapp/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM classificationbot/deploy-base:latest

COPY ./requirements-webapp.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements-webapp.txt

# OVERWRITE DEMO DATA WITH CUSTOM FOLDERS
COPY ./data /opt/bot/data
COPY ./pre_trained_weights /opt/bot/pre_trained_weights

# I ALSO TRIED TO OVERWRITE THIS FOLDER / FILES - SAME EXCEPTION
# COPY ./deepanimebot /opt/bot/deepanimebot
# COPY ./data.py /opt/bot/data.py
# COPY ./model.py /opt/bot/model.py
# COPY ./deploy.py /opt/bot/deploy.py

WORKDIR /opt/bot
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "-b", ":80", "deepanimebot.wsgi:app"]
```

Console:

```
$ docker build -t classificationbot/webapp:latest -f dockerfiles/webapp/Dockerfile .
...
Successfully built e1159596c19f
$ docker run e1159596c19f
[2016-11-06 14:39:38 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-11-06 14:39:38 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (1)
[2016-11-06 14:39:38 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-11-06 14:39:38 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
Using Theano backend.
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                       Output Shape        Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
convolution2d_1 (Convolution2D)    (None, 64, 126, 126)1792        convolution2d_input_1[0][0]      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
zeropadding2d_1 (ZeroPadding2D)    (None, 64, 128, 128)0           convolution2d_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_2 (Convolution2D)    (None, 64, 126, 126)36928       zeropadding2d_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 64, 63, 63)  0           convolution2d_2[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batchnormalization_1 (BatchNormaliz(None, 64, 63, 63)  126         maxpooling2d_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
zeropadding2d_2 (ZeroPadding2D)    (None, 64, 65, 65)  0           batchnormalization_1[0][0]       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_3 (Convolution2D)    (None, 128, 63, 63) 73856       zeropadding2d_2[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_4 (Convolution2D)    (None, 128, 63, 63) 16512       convolution2d_3[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 128, 31, 31) 0           convolution2d_4[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batchnormalization_2 (BatchNormaliz(None, 128, 31, 31) 62          maxpooling2d_2[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
zeropadding2d_3 (ZeroPadding2D)    (None, 128, 33, 33) 0           batchnormalization_2[0][0]       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_5 (Convolution2D)    (None, 256, 31, 31) 295168      zeropadding2d_3[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
zeropadding2d_4 (ZeroPadding2D)    (None, 256, 33, 33) 0           convolution2d_5[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_6 (Convolution2D)    (None, 256, 31, 31) 590080      zeropadding2d_4[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_7 (Convolution2D)    (None, 256, 31, 31) 65792       convolution2d_6[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 256, 15, 15) 0           convolution2d_7[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batchnormalization_3 (BatchNormaliz(None, 256, 15, 15) 30          maxpooling2d_3[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
zeropadding2d_5 (ZeroPadding2D)    (None, 256, 17, 17) 0           batchnormalization_3[0][0]       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_8 (Convolution2D)    (None, 512, 15, [2016-11-06 14:39:43 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/opt/bot/deepanimebot/wsgi.py", line 5, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/opt/bot/deepanimebot/webapp.py", line 50, in create_app
    app.config['MODEL_NAME']))
  File "/opt/bot/deepanimebot/classifiers.py", line 50, in __init__
    model_name=model_name)
  File "/opt/bot/deploy.py", line 26, in load_model
    model.load_weights("pre_trained_weights/latest_model_weights.hdf5")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2326, in load_weights
    str(len(flattened_layers)) + ' layers.')
Exception: You are trying to load a weight file containing 45 layers into a model with 34 layers.
[2016-11-06 14:39:43 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
[2016-11-06 14:39:43 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2016-11-06 14:39:43 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make changes to `dockerfiles/webapp/Dockerfile`, `deepanimebot/webapp.py`. This was, because the deepanimebot webapp was configured to use a different model (`deep_anime_model`) than the deepclassificationbot (`model`) and paths to `data/data.hdf5` were wrong across the `deepanimebot` module. Here are the files that required most changes:

`~/DeepClassificationBot-master/dockerfiles/webapp/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM classificationbot/deploy-base:latest

COPY ./requirements-webapp.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements-webapp.txt

COPY ./data /opt/bot/data
COPY ./pre_trained_weights /opt/bot/pre_trained_weights
COPY ./deepanimebot/webapp.py /opt/bot/deepanimebot/webapp.py

WORKDIR /opt/bot
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "-b", ":80", "deepanimebot.wsgi:app"]
```

`~/DeepClassificationBot-master/deepanimebot/webapp.py`

```
app.config.setdefault('DATASET_PATH', 'data/data.hdf5')
app.config.setdefault('INPUT_SHAPE', 256)
app.config.setdefault('MODEL_NAME', 'model')
```